# C# iteration and interpolation syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I got thrown into the deep end with a C# project. I'm brand new to Entity Framework, LINQ queries, Visual Studio, ASP.NET MVC, and C#. If this was Ruby or JavaScript I could do it no problem.

I need some help with the syntax for returning the required information. I have the logic about 2/3 completed, but I am just not sure how to iterate through my data and display it properly.

TL;DR - how do I iterate through the arrays (list1, list2, list3) and return it as the following?

```
"#{asset} violates the rules."
```

Here are the requirements I need to fulfill:

- pc date >= da date & da date >= afl date & afl date >= proposal date.
  Apply this rule only if asset category is development(=1) and pc date, da date, afl date and proposal date are not null.
- Asset didn't give all required fields (title, state, fund, gav, gla, and suburb).
- The sum of ownership of all funds should be 100% for each asset.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Program.EFServices
{
    public class DataAuditService
    {
        public static List<DIM_Assets> getAssets()
        {
            var context = new radiusEntities();
            var query1 = from l in context.DIM_Assets
                         where ((l.category_id.ToString() == "1" /* category is development (1) */
                                && (l.pc_date < l.da_date || l.da_date < l.afl_date || l.afl_date < l.proposal_date)
                                && (l.pc_date == null || l.da_date == null || l.afl_date == null || l.proposal_date == null)
                               ))
                         select l;

            var query2 = from l in context.DIM_Assets
                         where ((l.category_id.ToString() == "1" /* category is development (1) */
                                && /* sum of ownership = 100% */
                                (l.FT_Ownership.Sum(f => f.percent) != 100)
                               ))
                         select l;

            var query3 = from l in context.DIM_Assets
                         where ((l.category_id.ToString() == "1" /* category is development (1) */
                                 && (l.state_id == null || l.GAV == null || l.GLA == null || l.SUBURB == null || l.ASSET == null || l.FT_Ownership.Count == 0))
                               )
                         select l;

            var list1 = query1.ToList();
            var list2 = query2.ToList();
            var list3 = query3.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing the code you already added, explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Why are you doing `l.category_id.ToString() == "1"` instead of just `l.category_id == 1` (assuming it's an integer to begin with).

Comment: I'm really not sure what your asking, but `var x = list1.Select(a => $"{a.Name} violates the rules.").ToList()` would give you a list of strings where a name for the assets is used in each one (not sure what actual property/column name you actually need).

Comment: @zackraiyan I did explain what I'm trying to achieve.  list1 is an array of objects that violate those rules and so on. 

now i need to iterate through and return "#{object} violates the rules"

Comment: @juharr, yea I know.. I'm just focused on the iteration and interpolation syntax. I'm did it because i'm actually not sure, and I'm new to c#. thanks though!

Comment: There are other ways you can achieve your goal , not just LINQ,however i am not much clear of what you are trying to achieve..Why not explain your situation and goal in simple words ?

Comment: If you're satisfied with the results in your lists and only want to translate to a list of strings then just the code for the type of objects in the list, and the desired string is all you need in the question.  We'd only need to see the queries if you're not getting the desired results.

Comment: sure. sorry. I'm using .NET MVC, which I'm also brand new to. this file is the dataAudit settingsservice. I need to pass the results of the linq queries to the controller/view and say: "here are the objects that violate the rules, and here are the rules they violate."

what I'm asking for help with is putting these three list variables into a return value, and iterating over it in the view to display that.

my first inclination is to put these list variables into an array, and then iterate over that, but idk if that's the best thing to do

Comment: You requirement for comparing dates is >= while your code is using >.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for objects that violate the rules.  Please, my question is:

how do I utilize the return value of [list1, list2, list3] with the controller / view and iterate through it to interpolate the values?

Comment: What is "pc date", "da date", and "afl date"?

Comment: Is this all you are looking for? `list1.Select(l => $"#{l.AssetName} violates the rules.")`. With `.AssetName` being whatever property you want to display in the message.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified so I could test. This covers the iteration and an interpolated string. To use Debug.Print (appears in the Immediate Window) add a

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

to the top of the file.

```
private List<Coffee> coffees = new List<Coffee>();
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Coffee> cofList = GetCoffeeList();
            foreach (Coffee c in cofList)
            {
                Debug.Print($"{c.CoffeeName} roaster's ID is {c.RoasterId}");
            }
        }
        private List<Coffee> GetCoffeeList()
        {
            var query = from c in coffees
                        where (c.RoasterId == 1)
                        select c;
            return query.ToList<Coffee>();
        }
```